# How to switch fragment orientation on Navigation Graph in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigation-graph, android-studio-4.1

I added two fragments to a Navigation map in Android Studio and they appeared landscape.

I would like to switch them to portrait view to save view space. Can some help?

[image]

Comment: Press `O` button on your keyboard. (Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just press the key **O** (not zero) on your keyboard. The orientation will change only after you move the cursor.

Comment: Is this still supported? It always stays in portrait mode for me, even if I put all of my res files to layout-land folder.